# Send email with profile2 fields with account email token in rules

Tags: 7, rules, users, emails

I am trying to send an email to users contains information they put into their [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) fields when they registered on the website.

My problem is that their is no email field token available in rules and I was wondering if their is a way to expose the account email token so that I send emails to the user.

The rule I have setup is as follows and I have exported the rule which can be found below.

Event: After saving a new profile

Actions: Send HTML e-mail

```
{ "rules_email_banking_details" : {
    "LABEL" : "Email Banking Details",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "mimemail", "profile2" ],
    "ON" : { "profile2_insert" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "mimemail" : {
          "key" : "[site:name]",
          "to" : "[profile2:field_account_email]",
          "subject" : "Banking Details for accounts that you must make a  payment to.",
          "body" : "[profile2:field_name_of_your_bank]",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If anybody has some advice that could help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your token will be - [profile2:user:mail]. It is available in your rule with the setup that you described. You might not see it in replacement patterns for the "to" field when you are using "direct input" mode, but if you switch to "data selection" mode - you'll be able to find that token much easier.